# Switching back to "Week Rank" sorting in the reputation leagues is broken

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

I go to the user [league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/week/askubuntu/2024-01-28/1749634#1749634) and everything seems normal (*Note: Sort By is set to Week rank*):

[image]

When I change the "Sort By" to rank change, for example, it is still normal (*Sort By set to rank change*):

[image]

Now when I change it back (*Sort By set to Week Rank*):

[image]

Now it shows a user two times. After going through these steps, it stays like that until I close the website and open it again.

Comment: I think the feature is meant to show you always on top with your rank when you are in the result on that page. So the last two images are correct, the first isn't. I'm unsure what causes that because in my testing that top usercard is in the html that comes from the server. It almost looks like the server doesn't know for the first render which user you are, aka not "fully" logged in. or so. There is definitely something weird going on in your setup because I can't repro on Chrome latest.

Comment: @rene It's supposed to show you always on top with your rank when you are _not_ in the result on that page. In practice, it only shows you not on top if you're on the _first_ page: subsequent pages show at the top and on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to your user profile.
2. Click on the "top *n*% this *period*" link: this takes you to `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/siteid/period_type/sitename/period_date/userid#userid`, scrolling to the appropriate position in the list.
3. Change the sort type: this takes you to `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/siteid/period_type/sitename/period_date?sort=sorttype`
4. Change the sort type back: this takes you to `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/siteid/period_type/sitename/period_date?sort=reputationchange`. Note that this is a different URL to before.

I'm not certain that this is a bug, after all. I [completely misunderstood](/posts/comments1326175) the intended behaviour as well, but I do think that what we're seeing is intended. The goal is to allow you to see your ranking, and compare it to the ranking of others:

- Normally, it shows your entry at the top of the list; but
- when you use a link with the "scroll to the appropriate position in the list" behaviour, your entry will be at the top of the viewport, so that is unnecessary.